# Waits randomly not working in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, teamcity, browserstack

We have some UI tests written in selenium running with Browserstack on TeamCity.
These tests randomly fail because (in my opinion) the wait.Untils are not working correctly as the error always is 'could not click element ...  because element  would receive the click. As you can see in the code i apply multiple waits and still it randomly ignores them.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Login']")).Click();

        //wait for the page to be loaded, check the title and open a booking
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("To be completed")));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("To be completed")));
        Assert.AreEqual("Booking Overview", driver.Title);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button")));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("To be completed")));
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("To be completed")).Click();

        //wait for step 2 to load
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[@id='WiredWizardsteps']/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/label/span")));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@id='WiredWizardsteps']/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/label/span")));
        //verify we are at step 2
        var step2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[contains(@class, 'steps')]/li[contains(@class, 'active')]"));
        Assert.AreEqual("2", step2.GetAttribute("data-target"));
        //click the radiobutton with a movetoelement
        var option = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='WiredWizardsteps']/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/label/span"));
        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(option).Click().Perform();
        //retry programmatically
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='WiredWizardsteps']/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/label/span")).Click();
        //wait for the textbox to appear
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("commodityNonOperative")));
```

anybody has a suggestion or had the same problems please let me know.

Comment: Which line is it failing and what is it supposed to do when it's failing?

Comment: Are you sure that your XPaths are uniquely identifying elements on the page? - You may be inadvertently clicking another element located with the same expression.